# Why the timer is not showing the dots on the label as text each time less one?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Extract
{
    public partial class LoadingLabel : Label
    {
        private int TimeToCount = 300;
        private int Interval = 1000;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;
        private int counter = 0;

        public LoadingLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold);

            StartCountDownTimer(Interval, true);
        }

        public void StartCountDownTimer(int Interval, bool EnableTimer)
        {
            _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
            {
                Interval = Interval,
                Enabled = false
            };

            _timer.Enabled = EnableTimer;

            _timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    this.Text = ".";
                    Thread.Sleep(3);
                    counter++;
                }

                if(counter == 1)
                {
                    this.Text = "..";
                    Thread.Sleep(3);
                    counter++;
                }

                if(counter == 2)
                {
                    this.Text = "...";
                    Thread.Sleep(3);
                    counter = 0;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The interval is set to 1000 one second.

I want to use the interval so each second it will add another dot starting from one dot to three.
Then in the end when there are three dots start over again from one.

I tried for testing using a Thread.Sleep but it's not working it's showing only the last three dots and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `_timer.Tick` your `if`s are running sequentially.
You could replace 2nd and 3rd `if`s with `else if` or replace your code with the following:

```
if (counter == 3)
{
    this.Text = "";
    counter = 0;
}
this.Text += ".";
Thread.Sleep(3);
counter++;
```

Also you could eliminate the `counter` field since its value is always equal to the `Text.Length`.

Comment: Why when I drag the control to the form1 designer from the toolbox it's showing the label name loadingLabel1 and the dots near it ? how can I remove the name loadingLabel1 and show only the dots ? I tried in the constructor of the control to make this.Text = ""; but it didn't change anything also I tried this.Name = ""; and also it didn't remove the control name when dragging it in form1 designer.

Comment: I tried this but it's still showing loadingLabel1 when draggingi t in form1 designer from the toolbox :  public LoadingLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
            this.Text = "";
            this.Name = "";
            StartCountDownTimer(Interval, true);
        }

Comment: @SherylLarson This is another question, don't it? Can you just clear the label's `Text` in the properties panel in designer?

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple solution:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Text = "";
    timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    {
       Interval = 1000
    };
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Text.Contains("..."))
    {
       Text = "";
    }
    else
    {         
       Text += ".";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why when I drag the control to the form1 designer from the toolbox it's showing the label name loadingLabel1 and the dots near it ? how can I remove the name loadingLabel1 and show only the dots ? I tried in the constructor of the control to make this.Text = ""; but it didn't change anything also I tried this.Name = ""; and also it didn't remove the control name when dragging it in form1 designer.

Comment: I tried this but it's still showing loadingLabel1 when draggingi t in form1 designer from the toolbox :  public LoadingLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
            this.Text = "";
            this.Name = "";
            StartCountDownTimer(Interval, true);
        }

Comment: Just clear `Text` property